# Normalizing LUV-values to 0-255 range in openCV

Tags: opencv

I need to convert the values of a LUV-image to the range of 0-255.

As the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor) suggests I have to do it like this:

L = 255 / (100 * L)  (For example for each L-value)

But since the range of values for L is 0 <= L <= 100, I am wondering what happens when L = 0...

So, is my approach correct in general?

Greets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want convert the range of values from `[0,100]` to `[0,255]` you have to use `255 / 100 * L` not `255 / (100 * L)`. So there won't be a division by zero.